# c# oracle problem

Tags: c#, oracle

I am using c#.net with an Oracle database.

I want an example of how a dropdown list will fetch values from database name.  I want to know how to make an Oracle connection in c#.

I have searched  the net but have not got exactly what I require.

plz add comment tag to understand me.

Thank you

Comment: Is dropdrip meant to be dropdown? So you want to connect to Oracle to get a list of items to show in a dropdown list?

Comment: yes..sorry i have edited the question

Comment: i hav not satisfying with the answer.plz reply to this question as possible

Comment: What is wrong with the answer you have been given?

Comment: firstly i need to bind the data with the dropdown list from with the database using oracle connectivity.and in the which someone given has been not according to me satisying with question.i hav followed the tutorial,its not good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that you use the Oracle provided [ODP.NET](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/windows/odpnet/index.html). They also have some getting started tutorials that should help get you on your way.

http://www.oracle.com/technology/obe/hol08/dotnet/getstarted-c/getstarted_c_otn.htm